# Como transformar a classe de uma coluna "factor" em "date" dentro de um data.frame?

Tags: r, classes, data.frame

Eu tenho uma base extraída em csv `(dados_base)`, com o período de dez/2017 a jan/2019, que possui três colunas: `USUARIO`, `DT_PAGTO` e `VL_PED_PG`, onde o primeiro campo representa os usuários com a classe `"integer"`, o segundo campo representa a data de pagamento com a classe `"factor"` e o terceiro campo representa o valor em reais com a classe `"numeric"`. No meu caso eu preciso transformar a coluna `DT_PAGTO` de classe `"factor"` para `"date"`.

Eu tentei usar o `mutate`:

```
dados_base2 = dados_base %>%
  mutate(DT_PAGTO = as.Date(DT_PAGTO,"%d/%m/%y"))

class(dados_base$DT_PAGTO)
[1] "Date"

print(dados_base2$DT_PAGTO)
[1] "2020-12-20"
```

Na minha tentativa a classe é transformada com sucesso, mas o formato da data não corresponde com a data original do csv. Existe outra maneira de transformar a classe? Que erro estou cometendo?

Segue o `dput` para auxiliar no entendimento:

```
dput(head(dados_base, 50))
structure(list(USUARIO = c(282746L, 6651152L, 6622750L, 183147L, 
833097L, 5654010L, 62129L, 640459L, 283914L, 6833181L, 843495L, 
6696269L, 179480L, 71173L, 203562L, 979164L, 6747726L, 5683083L, 
6797883L, 245945L, 373197L, 25797L, 599336L, 827926L, 6728407L, 
6815081L, 244841L, 6797883L, 370121L, 211326L, 6825906L, 35976L, 
6614515L, 83303L, 373197L, 473348L, 350239L, 191273L, 364387L, 
294993L, 6781972L, 288423L, 6447749L, 173166L, 165653L, 6652688L, 
6690957L, 978119L, 597592L, 487315L), DT_PAGTO = structure(c(260L, 
260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 
260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 
260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 
260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 
260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L), .Label = c("01/01/2018", "01/01/2019", 
"01/02/2018", "01/03/2018", "01/04/2018", "01/05/2018", "01/06/2018", 
"01/07/2018", "01/08/2018", "01/09/2018", "01/10/2018", "01/11/2018", 
"01/12/2018", "02/01/2018", "02/01/2019", "02/02/2018", "02/03/2018", 
"02/04/2018", "02/05/2018", "02/06/2018", "02/07/2018", "02/08/2018", 
"02/09/2018", "02/10/2018", "02/11/2018", "02/12/2018", "03/01/2018", 
"03/01/2019", "03/02/2018", "03/03/2018", "03/04/2018", "03/05/2018", 
"03/06/2018", "03/07/2018", "03/08/2018", "03/09/2018", "03/10/2018", 
"03/11/2018", "03/12/2018", "04/01/2018", "04/01/2019", "04/02/2018", 
"04/03/2018", "04/04/2018", "04/05/2018", "04/06/2018", "04/07/2018", 
"04/08/2018", "04/09/2018", "04/10/2018", "04/11/2018", "04/12/2018", 
"05/01/2018", "05/01/2019", "05/02/2018", "05/03/2018", "05/04/2018", 
"05/05/2018", "05/06/2018", "05/07/2018", "05/08/2018", "05/09/2018", 
"05/10/2018", "05/11/2018", "05/12/2018", "06/01/2018", "06/01/2019", 
"06/02/2018", "06/03/2018", "06/04/2018", "06/05/2018", "06/06/2018", 
"06/07/2018", "06/08/2018", "06/09/2018", "06/10/2018", "06/11/2018", 
"06/12/2018", "07/01/2018", "07/01/2019", "07/02/2018", "07/03/2018", 
"07/04/2018", "07/05/2018", "07/06/2018", "07/07/2018", "07/08/2018", 
"07/09/2018", "07/10/2018", "07/11/2018", "07/12/2018", "08/01/2018", 
"08/01/2019", "08/02/2018", "08/03/2018", "08/04/2018", "08/05/2018", 
"08/06/2018", "08/07/2018", "08/08/2018", "08/09/2018", "08/10/2018", 
"08/11/2018", "08/12/2018", "09/01/2018", "09/01/2019", "09/02/2018", 
"09/03/2018", "09/04/2018", "09/05/2018", "09/06/2018", "09/07/2018", 
"09/08/2018", "09/09/2018", "09/10/2018", "09/11/2018", "09/12/2018", 
"10/01/2018", "10/01/2019", "10/02/2018", "10/03/2018", "10/04/2018", 
"10/05/2018", "10/06/2018", "10/07/2018", "10/08/2018", "10/09/2018", 
"10/10/2018", "10/11/2018", "10/12/2018", "11/01/2018", "11/01/2019", 
"11/02/2018", "11/03/2018", "11/04/2018", "11/05/2018", "11/06/2018", 
"11/07/2018", "11/08/2018", "11/09/2018", "11/10/2018", "11/11/2018", 
"11/12/2018", "12/01/2018", "12/01/2019", "12/02/2018", "12/03/2018", 
"12/04/2018", "12/05/2018", "12/06/2018", "12/07/2018", "12/08/2018", 
"12/09/2018", "12/10/2018", "12/11/2018", "12/12/2018", "13/01/2018", 
"13/01/2019", "13/02/2018", "13/03/2018", "13/04/2018", "13/05/2018", 
"13/06/2018", "13/07/2018", "13/08/2018", "13/09/2018", "13/10/2018", 
"13/11/2018", "13/12/2018", "14/01/2018", "14/01/2019", "14/02/2018", 
"14/03/2018", "14/04/2018", "14/05/2018", "14/06/2018", "14/07/2018", 
"14/08/2018", "14/09/2018", "14/10/2018", "14/11/2018", "14/12/2018", 
"15/01/2018", "15/01/2019", "15/02/2018", "15/03/2018", "15/04/2018", 
"15/05/2018", "15/06/2018", "15/07/2018", "15/08/2018", "15/09/2018", 
"15/10/2018", "15/11/2018", "15/12/2018", "16/01/2018", "16/01/2019", 
"16/02/2018", "16/03/2018", "16/04/2018", "16/05/2018", "16/06/2018", 
"16/07/2018", "16/08/2018", "16/09/2018", "16/10/2018", "16/11/2018", 
"16/12/2018", "17/01/2018", "17/01/2019", "17/02/2018", "17/03/2018", 
"17/04/2018", "17/05/2018", "17/06/2018", "17/07/2018", "17/08/2018", 
"17/09/2018", "17/10/2018", "17/11/2018", "17/12/2018", "18/01/2018", 
"18/01/2019", "18/02/2018", "18/03/2018", "18/04/2018", "18/05/2018", 
"18/06/2018", "18/07/2018", "18/08/2018", "18/09/2018", "18/10/2018", 
"18/11/2018", "18/12/2018", "19/01/2018", "19/01/2019", "19/02/2018", 
"19/03/2018", "19/04/2018", "19/05/2018", "19/06/2018", "19/07/2018", 
"19/08/2018", "19/09/2018", "19/10/2018", "19/11/2018", "19/12/2018", 
"20/01/2018", "20/01/2019", "20/02/2018", "20/03/2018", "20/04/2018", 
"20/05/2018", "20/06/2018", "20/07/2018", "20/08/2018", "20/09/2018", 
"20/10/2018", "20/11/2018", "20/12/2017", "20/12/2018", "21/01/2018", 
"21/01/2019", "21/02/2018", "21/03/2018", "21/04/2018", "21/05/2018", 
"21/06/2018", "21/07/2018", "21/08/2018", "21/09/2018", "21/10/2018", 
"21/11/2018", "21/12/2017", "21/12/2018", "22/01/2018", "22/01/2019", 
"22/02/2018", "22/03/2018", "22/04/2018", "22/05/2018", "22/06/2018", 
"22/07/2018", "22/08/2018", "22/09/2018", "22/10/2018", "22/11/2018", 
"22/12/2017", "22/12/2018", "23/01/2018", "23/01/2019", "23/02/2018", 
"23/03/2018", "23/04/2018", "23/05/2018", "23/06/2018", "23/07/2018", 
"23/08/2018", "23/09/2018", "23/10/2018", "23/11/2018", "23/12/2017", 
"23/12/2018", "24/01/2018", "24/01/2019", "24/02/2018", "24/03/2018", 
"24/04/2018", "24/05/2018", "24/06/2018", "24/07/2018", "24/08/2018", 
"24/09/2018", "24/10/2018", "24/11/2018", "24/12/2017", "24/12/2018", 
"25/01/2018", "25/02/2018", "25/03/2018", "25/04/2018", "25/05/2018", 
"25/06/2018", "25/07/2018", "25/08/2018", "25/09/2018", "25/10/2018", 
"25/11/2018", "25/12/2017", "25/12/2018", "26/01/2018", "26/02/2018", 
"26/03/2018", "26/04/2018", "26/05/2018", "26/06/2018", "26/07/2018", 
"26/08/2018", "26/09/2018", "26/10/2018", "26/11/2018", "26/12/2017", 
"26/12/2018", "27/01/2018", "27/02/2018", "27/03/2018", "27/04/2018", 
"27/05/2018", "27/06/2018", "27/07/2018", "27/08/2018", "27/09/2018", 
"27/10/2018", "27/11/2018", "27/12/2017", "27/12/2018", "28/01/2018", 
"28/02/2018", "28/03/2018", "28/04/2018", "28/05/2018", "28/06/2018", 
"28/07/2018", "28/08/2018", "28/09/2018", "28/10/2018", "28/11/2018", 
"28/12/2017", "28/12/2018", "29/01/2018", "29/03/2018", "29/04/2018", 
"29/05/2018", "29/06/2018", "29/07/2018", "29/08/2018", "29/09/2018", 
"29/10/2018", "29/11/2018", "29/12/2017", "29/12/2018", "30/01/2018", 
"30/03/2018", "30/04/2018", "30/05/2018", "30/06/2018", "30/07/2018", 
"30/08/2018", "30/09/2018", "30/10/2018", "30/11/2018", "30/12/2017", 
"30/12/2018", "31/01/2018", "31/03/2018", "31/05/2018", "31/07/2018", 
"31/08/2018", "31/10/2018", "31/12/2017", "31/12/2018"), class = "factor"), 
    VL_PED_PG = c(30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 20, 30, 50, 10, 46.2, 20, 
    50, 22.8, 30, 50, 20, 30, 50, 10, 30, 10, 20, 30, 40, 15.2, 
    20, 20, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 40.03, 20, 8, 50, 10, 30, 30, 
    30, 10, 20, 50, 30, 20, 20, 10, 20, 30, 20)), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu acho a função `as.Date` bastante ruim. Muitas vezes tenho problemas com ela e sei não exatamente como resolver. Por isso, sugiro usar o pacote `lubridate` para trabalhar com datas. Em vez de colocar formatos tipo `"%d/%m/%y"` para criar objetos de data, o pacote `lubridate` tem funções específicas e bastante intuitivas para fazer isso.

Como as tuas datas estão no formato dia, mês e ano, a função adequada do `lubridate` para converter este valores para data é `dmy` (day, month, year):

```
library(lubridate)
dados_base$DT_PAGTO <- dmy(dados_base$DT_PAGTO)
is.Date(dados_base$DT_PAGTO)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 5):

Ao importar o arquivo `csv` inclua o argumento `stringAsFactors = FALSE`, assim a sua coluna com as datas será lida como `character`.

Depois é só aplicar o `mutate` como você está fazendo. Só note que como o ano das suas datas estão "completos", o argumento da função `as.Date` deve ser `"%d/%m/%Y"`.

Comment: Olá!  Como faço para incluir `stringAsFactors = FALSE` ?

Comment: na leitura do arquivo, `read.csv("arquivo.csv", header = T, ..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Olá! Vou testar.